# Does attrs.$observe unregister when the directive is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand that unlike $watch, $observe does not return unregister function.

So the question is - if I have an $observe on attribute inside a directive, and the directive is destroyed, does angular clean the $observe after itself?

If not, what is the angular-way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Angular 1.3.0, there was no way of unregistering `$observe`. Since Angular 1.3.0, [`$observe` returns the unregister function](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/299b220f5e05e1d4e26bfd58d0b2fd7329ca76b1).

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is memory leaks (as it was mine), I put together a jsbin to try and see how memory behaves and use chrome inspector to check it:

https://jsbin.com/luhewutetu/4/edit?html,js,output

I've clicked "Add" a bunch of times, then waited a bit and then clicked "Remove". I then forced garbage collection via devtools.

This is the resulting heap curve:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the heap grows bigger and bigger as I add elements, but when I remove all off them and force garbage collection it goes back to the initial value.

So, from this simple experiment, it seems like the answer is no, `attribute.$observe` listener do not, in *general* need to be deregistered.